# Native script - Convert base64 string to image and store it in local file system

Tags: nativescript

In my requirement, we need to take digital signature. Digital signature we are receiving it as base 64 string.
Is any way to convert base64 to image in native script.

Answer (score 0):

[Official NativeScript Docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/image-source#creating-png-image-file-from-base64-string) for the `image-source` module have the following

```
let img: imageSource.ImageSource;
img = imageSource.fromBase64(jpgImageAsBase64String);
```

Which loads the image in memory from the string. Following you can save the image calling the `saveToFile` method of image-source instances

```
let saved = imageSource.saveToFile(path, "png");
if (saved) {
   console.log("Image saved successfully!");
}
```